# Multiple shell commands executed in one process in groovy script

Tags: shell, groovy, npm, process

I want to fetch a npm package and untar it in a groovy script like so:

```
def cmd = "cd .composerpages/umanagement && npm pack @mag-umanagement/umanagement-pages-v2810@^28.10.4-SNAPSHOT && tar xvzf *.tgz"
cmd.execute()
```

Unfortunately, it executes only the first term (cd .composerpages/umanagement).

Is there a way to have multiple commands executed in one shell process?

Answer (score 3):

If you need all the "shell-isms" there, then just let the shell handle it (with `-c`).   E.g.:

```
def cmd = "cd .composerpages/umanagement && npm pack @mag-umanagement/umanagement-pages-v2810@^28.10.4-SNAPSHOT && tar xvzf *.tgz"
["/bin/sh", "-c", cmd].execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to execute all the options and not `&&` them.

This is how you should approach it:

```
def cmd = 'cd .composerpages/umanagement'.execute() | 'npm pack @mag-umanagement/umanagement-pages-v2810@^28.10.4-SNAPSHOT'.execute() | 'tar xvzf *.tgz'.execute()
cmd.waitFor()
println cmd.text
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can try tokenizing your pipeline of commands to a list of commands and execute them in sequence as long as they return exit code `0` (`&&` stops command pipeline when the command returns nonzero exit code). Consider following example:

```
def cmd = 'echo test && echo foo && exit 1 && echo 123'

cmd.tokenize('&&').every {
  try {
    def p = it.execute()
    def output = p.text.trim()

    p.waitFor()

    println output

    return p.exitValue() == 0
  } catch (e) {
    return false
  }
}
```

Here we have a pipeline of 4 commands:

- `echo test`
- `echo foo`
- `exit 1`
- `echo 123`

Chaining these commands with AND operator (`&&`) expects stopping the pipeline after `exit 1`.

Groovy's `Iterable.every(Closure closure)` method executes as long as returned predicate is `true`. In our case we continue iterating over the list of commands as long as exit code is `0`.

Running above example produces following output to console:

```
test
foo
```

Comment: I think, this will run in different sub-processes.